# Иконка не ассоциируется с файлами .py

Tags: python, windows

Понимаю, что вопрос не совсем сюда, но думаю местная аудитория подскажет решение.

На компьютере Windows 10 установлен Python 3.5. Все файлы в каталогах с расширение .py имеют белую иконку, а не фирменный значок Phyton.

Пробовал переустановить - в настройках галка ассоциации файлов .py стояла. Переустановка не помогла. Как можно это исправить?
Просто вызывает неудобство.

Спасибо.

Comment: В реестре программ по умолчанию Python,IDLE вообще отсутствуют.

Comment: Версия Python 3.7 - та же проблема. Причем устанавливал в одном классе - все без проблем, установил в другом - при запуске программы выдается ошибка. Насколько понимаю, файлы .py не ассоциируются с python. Что делать? Или все также "Open with ..."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правой кнопкой мыши на один из .py файлов -> Properties -> В строчке "открывать с помощью" нажимаем на Change -> Нажимаем на кнопку Browse, если пайтона нет в списке програм -> Находим папку с Пайтоном и выбираем python.exe -> ОК -> ОК.
Все! :)

Comment: Небольшое замечание: Python в списке программ есть, но при ручном выборе python.exe проблема решается, а при выборе из предложенного списка программ - нет.

Comment: Замечание: Если так сделать, то из меню мыши пропадает кнопка "Edit with IDLE".

Answer (score 3):

Это похоже на баг в установщике для Питон 3.5: [Windows installer assigns non-existent icons to Python file types](http://bugs.python.org/issue25112) -- `py.exe` содержит только одну иконку.

Явный выбор `python.exe`, [как предложил @Michael Vaysman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/452177/23044), может помочь, если только одна версия Питона на машине стоит (в противном случае shebang (`#!python2`, `#!python3.3`) будет игнорироваться).

Выпуск Python 3.5.1 должен поправить эту и другие проблемы с установкой.